# Alter the content of a pandas column by regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with a column that looks like this

```
Other via Other on 17 Jan   2019 
Other via Other on 17 Jan   2019 
Interview via E-mail    on  14  Dec 2018
Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
Interview via   E-mail  on  14  Jan 2019
Rejected via Website on 12 Jan  2019
```

Is it possible to split this column into two, one is whatever before the "via" and the other is whatever after the "on"? Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do df[column].split(r'via.*on', expand=True)

Comment: @MegaBluejay What if I also want to remove anything that is after that date in the original column?

Answer (score 0):

Use str.extract

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df.col.str.extract('(.*)\svia.*on\s(.*)', expand = True)

    col1        col2
0   Other       17 Jan 2019
1   Other       17 Jan 2019
2   Interview   14 Dec 2018
3   Rejected    15 Jan 2019
4   Rejected    15 Jan 2019
5   Rejected    15 Jan 2019
6   Rejected    15 Jan 2019
7   Interview   14 Jan 2019
8   Rejected    12 Jan 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much use split() as  `df.col.str.split('via|on',expand=True)[[0,2]`:

Lets details it out........

**Reproducing Your DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
                                        col
0         Other via Other on 17 Jan   2019
1         Other via Other on 17 Jan   2019
2  Interview via E-mail    on  14  Dec 2018
3  Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
4  Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
5  Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
6  Rejected via    E-mail  on  15  Jan 2019
7  Interview via   E-mail  on  14  Jan 2019
8      Rejected via Website on 12 Jan  2019
```

Let's looks at here First splitting the whole column based on the our required strings `via` and `on` which will split the entire column `col` into three distinct separated columns `0 1 2` where `0` will be before the string `via` & `2` will be after string `on` and rest will be middle one which is column `1` which we don't require.

So, we can take liberty and only opt for columns `0` & `2` as follows.

```
>>> df.col.str.split('via|on',expand=True)[[0,2]]
            0                2
0      Other    17 Jan   2019
1      Other    17 Jan   2019
2  Interview      14  Dec 2018
3   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
4   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
5   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
6   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
7  Interview      14  Jan 2019
8   Rejected      12 Jan  2019
```

Better do it assign a new dataframe and the rename the columns:

**Result:**

```
newdf = df.col.str.split('via|on',expand=True)[[0,2]]
newdf.rename(columns={0: 'col1', 2: 'col2'}, inplace=True)
print(newdf)

         col1             col2
0      Other      17 Jan   2019
1      Other      17 Jan   2019
2  Interview      14  Dec 2018
3   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
4   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
5   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
6   Rejected      15  Jan 2019
7  Interview      14  Jan 2019
8   Rejected      12 Jan  2019
```